# Number of faces with 4 vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> In a $3$-regular (all vertices have degree $3$), plane and connected graph $G$, all faces have either $4$ or $6$ edges (even the unlimited face). How many faces have $4$ edges?

Given the properties of the graph, we know that:

$$\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  v - e + f = 2 \hfill \\
  3v = 2e \hfill \\
  3v \geqslant e + 6 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  v - e + f = 2 \hfill \\
  e \geqslant 6 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$

The first one is Euler's formula, the second one was derived from the fact that the sum of all degrees is $2*|E|$, and the third one comes from the fact that the graph is planar and connected.

How is it possible to find the number of faces with only $4$ edges?

Comment: Since this is my favorite kind of graph, may I ask what your interest is?

Comment: @draks, how do you mean? do you mean in general or specific to discrete maths?

Comment: In this type of graphs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the $F_4=6$. Use
$$F = F_4+F_6$$
$$ 3V\overset{1.}{=}2E  \overset{2.}{=} 4F_4+6F_6,$$
since $1.$ the graph is $3$-regular and $2.$ each face contributes its edges twice. We substitute this info in Euler's formula $6(V-E+F)=6\cdot 2$ and get:

$$
6V-6E+6F = 12\\
4E-6E+6F = 12\\
6F-2E = 12\\
6( F_4+F_6)-(4F_4+6F_6)=12\\
2F_4+0F_6 = 12\\
F_4=6
$$

Comment: I don't think I follow you in "Since each face contributes its edges twice;". Where is this fact applied?

Comment: @artem at $2E=4F_4+6F_6$

Comment: @Artem you see?

Comment: I think I see what you mean: You multiply the Euler's formula by 6 (lcm of 2 and 3), and then substitute the info we already have. What I did not get was the argument the sentence in question was related to: the above or the Euler's formula. Although equally valid, I think @ParchyTaxel description 'Since all edges are shared by two faces,' made more sense to me.

Comment: @Artem I edited the answer for more clarity...

Answer (score 4):

Let there be $F$ 4-edged faces and $S$ 6-edged faces. Since all edges are shared by two faces, we have $\frac{4F+6S}2=2F+3S$ edges. Since the graph is 3-regular, $4F+6S$ half-edges meet in one-third or $\frac43F+2S$ vertices.

Then Euler's formula gives
$$\frac43F+2S-2F-3S+F+S=2$$
$$\frac13F=2$$
$$F=6$$
Hence there are always six four-edged faces, as can be seen in the graphs of the cube and truncated octahedron.

Comment: Your answer is as good as the one above, however, since @daks posted it first, I chose to mark it accepted answer. Both your and daks answers helped me to solve this question. Thank you! :)